# How can I not merge all stylesheets in my Rails development environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

In my development environment I don't want all the stylesheets be combined in one application.source.scss file, so I can easier inspect the different style elements and locate them in the different stylesheets.

I thought adding the code `config.assets.debug = true` in my config/enviroments/development would do the trick, but it doesn't.

Is there a way that I still have all stylesheets load separately?

Comment: You ain't gonna need it. Rails 5+ provides source maps that link back to the original file so you can see where the rule is defined in the web inspector.

Comment: Somehow it's showing as one big application.source.scss file in my inspector. Should I enable souremapping somewhere?